# Is it possible to call an action defined in indexController from jQuery.ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, zend-framework, jquery

I am trying to call an action defined inside the indexController using the Jquery.Ajax. But there is nothing happens. Since I am new to Zend and Ajax, I don't have any idea What was happening.

Is it possible to do so?

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: Could you provide your code how you use Jquery.Ajax and eventually from index action?

Comment: Do you have the route for indexController properly setup(can you access using just the browser?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as far as I know, this has always worked for me:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "/module/controller/action",
   data: "id=5",
   success: function( response ){
     alert( 'ok:'+response );
   },
   error: function ( response ){
     alert( 'not ok:'+response )
   }
 });
```

Are you sure you can access the controller action via browser (try that to make sure it works)? It could be just a matter of mod_rewrite turned off in php.ini.

Could you post some code and explain what problem you're having?

Also try checking the Firefox error console (there are useful JavaScript errors and warnings sometimes).